# Converting a string of hexadecimal valiues into an array of bytes using Scanner in Java

Tags: java, hex, java.util.scanner

I would like to convert a string with the form "AA BB CC" or "0xAA 0xBB 0xCC" to an array of bytes. Reading the documentation of `Scanner` looked promising.

I assumed that `hasNextByte()` and `getNextByte()` would do the job but in fact not byte seems to be detected. The code is pretty simple:

```
byte[] bytesFromString(String value) {

    List<Byte> list = new ArrayList<>();
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(value);
    while(scan.hasNextByte(16)) {
     list.add(scan.nextByte(16));
    }

    byte[] bytes = new byte[list.size()];
    for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){
        bytes[i] = list.get(i);
    }
    return bytes;
}
```

I always receive an empty array as output: `hasNextByte(16)` never detects the byte.

Any particular reason why it is not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your values (`AA` `BB` and `CC`) are out of range for `byte`, since `byte` is signed.

A possible workaround is to read the values as `short` and then cast to `byte`:

```
while (scan.hasNextShort(16)) {
    list.add((byte) scan.nextShort(16));
}
```

Printing the results, you will see that the values are negative:

```
String input = "AA BB CC";
byte[] result = bytesFromString(input);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result)); // [-86, -69, -52]
```

Showing the overflow.